# Find a formula that is $0$ when $x<5$, $0.5$ when $5\leq x\leq 10$ and $1$ when $x>10$

Tags: functions

So we have $K$, and $K = x - f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is an expression that equals $0.5$ when $5 \le x \le 10$, and "some formula" will equal $0$ when $ x < 5$ and $1$ when $x > 10$. I thought using $-\sin(x)$ in some way would be potentially pointing in the right direction, however, I feel that there is a simpler way to do this that I can't comprehend.

Comment: Are there any additional properties that $f(x)$ should have (continous for instance) or will anything do? If so, why not just say: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x<5\\0.5,& 5\leq x \leq 10\\1,& x>10\end{cases}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible formula that may help:

$$f(x)=0.5((min(max(\left \lfloor (0.199999(x-5) \right \rfloor, -1), 1))+1)$$

(If you're not familiar with them, $\left \lfloor \right \rfloor$ denote the floor function. It's a fancy way of telling the formula to truncate the number and leave an integer.)

This formula basically works in a few steps:

1. Take x and subtract 5 from it. (This assures that any $x$ less than 5 becomes negative, and any number greater than 10 becomes greater than 5.)
2. Multiply by the result from step #1 by 0.199999. (This assures that any $x$ from 5 to up to 10 (plus 1/10,000) becomes a number ranging from zero up to less than 1. All other numbers become either negative or at least 1.)
3. Truncate any decimals the result from step #2. (This assures that any $x$ originally ranging from 5 to 10 (plus 1/10,000) is now 0. Anything above that range is a positive integer. Anything below that range is a negative integer.)
4. Take the result from step #3 and find the bigger integer between it and -1. (This assures that $x$ becomes no less than -1.)
5. Take the result from step #4 and find the smaller number between it and 1. (This assures that we now have an integer equal to -1 for $x$ up to 4.999, 0 for $x$ for numbers greater than 4.9991 up to 10.0001, and 1 for any $x$ higher than that.)
6. Take the result from step #5 and add 1 to it. (Any $x$ from 4.9991 to 10.0001 is now 1. Any $x$ lower than that is 0, and any $x$ higher than that is now 2.)
7. Multiply the result from step #6 by 0.5. (Any $x$ greater than 4.999 up to 10.0001 is now 0.5. Any $x$ lower than that is 0, and any $x$ higher than that is now 1.)

Here's a Desmos plot of the solution set: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j3r1djdrmc

Side note: gebruiker and fleablood both note that a piecewise function is suitable in this case. It really is the way to go. Note that the piecewise function approach captures the range precisely, while my single line formula only gets close to the function.

I knew this when creating the formula, but wanted to show that, while you can create a single-line function to solve a problem, it can be a lot of work when there's a simpler solution at hand.

---

Brayden now mentions that $x \geq 10$ should return $1$, so I'm reposting the original version below:

Here's a possible formula that may help:

$$f(x)=0.5\left \lfloor 0.2(min(max(x,0),10)) \right \rfloor$$

(If you're not familiar with them, ⌊⌋⌊⌋ denote the floor function. It's a fancy way of telling the formula to truncate the number and leave an integer.)

This formula basically works in a few steps:

1. What's the biggest number, x and 0? (This assures we're working with a non-negative number.)
2. What's the smallest number, 10 or the result from step #1? (This assures that we're working with a number from 0 to 10.)
3. Take the result from step #2, and multiply it by 0.2. (This reduces the possible values to a number from 0 to 2. Anything from 0 to 4.999 becomes 0 to 0.9998. Anything from 5 to 9.999 becomes 1 to 1.9998, and 10 becomes 2.)
4. Take the result from step #3, and truncate any decimals. (Anything from 0 to 0.9999 becomes 0. Anything from 1 to 1.9999 becomes 1, and 2 remains as 2.)
5. Take the result from step #4, and multiply it by 0.5. This assures us that we'll get a result of 0, 0.5 or 1.)

Here's a Desmos plot of the solution set: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mofoarr0g0

Comment: Nice formula, but it gives the wrong value at $x=a=10$.  The OP wants $f(10)=0.5$, not $1$.

Comment: As a possible way to rectify your solution: put the floor function inside your clipping function $\min(\max(a,x),b)$ with the appropriate constants.

Comment: Good catch, Barry! It has now been corrected, using J.M.'s idea.

Comment: @BarryCipra $f(x) = 1, \ when \ x \ge 10$ sorry I probably wrote that wrong somewhere.

Comment: In that case, Brayden, my original version will work: https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2289264/4

Comment: @GreyMatters All works well thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the formula you want is:

$f(x) = 0$ when $x < 5$; $f(x) = .5$ when $5 \le x \le 10$ and $f(x) = 1$ when $x > 10$.

That's it.  That is the formula.  And, yes, that satisfies all the requirements of a formula

Okay, this is huge pet peeve of mine but math isn't magic where everything needs a special incantation.  The naive and common misconception that one needs a "formula" to express something and that simply .... *expressing* ... it is somehow not allowed is just worng and causes for too many headaches.